# Why is Mathematica not able to give out a simple integration result?

Tags: numerical-integration, evaluation

I am testing Mathematica to evaluate an innocuous integral - It is a straightforward integration but just involves a lot of constants. I do not understand - "why the computation has exceeded the standard computation time."

```
ClearAll["Global`*"] 
rules = {a :> -h/q, b:> -1/g,  z:> (q*t)/g , p :> -r*t};

 L  = Normal[(Gamma[a - b + 1]/Gamma[1 - b]) E^(z + p) Gamma[
 1 - a] ((-(Gamma[b - 1]/Pi)) ((-z^(1 - b)) Sin[
       Pi a] + (-z)^(1 - b) Sin[Pi (b - a)]) Series[
    Hypergeometric1F1[1 - a, 2 - b, -z], {z, 0, 3}] )] //. rules  

Integrate[L,{ t , 0 , infinity}, Assumptions ->{g < -0.5 , q > 0 ,  r = q/(2g) + I (1/g)}  ]
```

The expression of L looks like this:

[image]

It should not be too difficult to evaluate the exponential terms, but yet, the computation exceeds the time limit. I am at my wit's end. Please help!

Comment: Remember. All math software are `case sensitive` which are available for purchase on our Earth Planet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Edit

Henrik Schumacher pointed out a mistake in this answer. I believe this edit corrects the error.

By changing your code to

```
rules = {a :> -h/q, b :> -1/g, z :> -(q*t)/g, p :> -(q/(2 g) + I (1/g))*t};

L =
  (Normal[
    (Gamma[a - b + 1]/Gamma[1 - b]) E^(z + p) Gamma[1 - a] 
      ((-(Gamma[b - 1]/Pi)) ((-z^(1 - b)) Sin[Pi a] + (-z)^(1 - b) Sin[Pi (b - a)]) 
      Series[Hypergeometric1F1[1 - a, 2 - b, -z], {z, 0, 3}])]
  /. rules);

Integrate[L, {t, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {g < -1/2, q > 0}]
```

I get the error message `Integrate::idiv`

[image: idiv]

indicating that the integral diverges on the interval of integration. So there is no solution under your assumptions.

Note the changes that I made:

- Eliminated `r` by writing p :> -(q/(2 g) + I (1/g))*t
- Replaced `infinity` with `Infinity`

Interestingly, removing the assumptions and evaluating

```
Integrate[L, {t, 0, Infinity}]
```

gives

[image: result]

in about 30 seconds and supplies conditions under which the integral converges.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `p :> -(q/(2 g) + I (1/g))*t`? It leads to error Integrate::idiv.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher. Yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing out my error. I will update the answer. Evaluating the integral without assumptions is valid.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica is case sensitive, so it should be `Infinity` instead of `infinity`.

Moreover, you might want to write `r = q/(2g) + I (1/g)` before the `Integrate`. So, the following executes and tells me that the integral does not exist:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
r = q/(2 g) + I (1/g);
rules = {a :> -h/q, b :> -1/g, z :> (q*t)/g, p :> -r*t};
L = Normal[(Gamma[a - b + 1]/Gamma[1 - b]) E^(z + p) Gamma[
      1 - a] ((-(Gamma[b - 1]/Pi)) ((-z^(1 - b)) Sin[
           Pi a] + (-z)^(1 - b) Sin[Pi (b - a)]) Series[
        Hypergeometric1F1[1 - a, 2 - b, -z], {z, 0, 3}])] //. rules;

Integrate[L, {t, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {g < -0.5, q > 0}]
```